# How to remove all XML children nodes but not attributes in Powershell

Tags: powershell

From this :

```
<products id="col">
  <product code="id1" />
  <product code="id2" />
</products>
```

I want to get this :

```
<products id="col">
</products>
```

If I use RemoveAll() it will remove products id attribute also so I will get this

```
<products>
</products>
```

That's not what I want. What method could I use to keep my id attribute in products node ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of calling `RemoveAll()`, you need to find the nodes you want to remove and then remove each of them manually, with `RemoveChild()`:

```
$XmlDocument = [xml]@'
<products id="col">
  <product code="id1" />
  <product code="id2" />
</products>
'@

$ChildNodes = $XmlDocument.SelectNodes('//product')

foreach($Child in $ChildNodes){
    [void]$Child.ParentNode.RemoveChild($Child)
}

$XmlDocument.Save("C:\path\to\doc.xml")
```

If you don't know the name of the immediate child nodes, but only the parent node name, you can use XPath to select them anyways: `'//ParentNodeName/child::*'`

```
$ChildNodes = $XmlDocument.SelectNodes('//products/child::*')
```

Answer (score 3):

My answer doesn't rely on XPath to accomplish this. The script assumes `$XmlDocument` is a variable containing an `XmlDocument` instance. The script also assumes that only `<product>` elements live inside `<products>`.

```
if ($XmlDocument.products -is [Xml.XmlElement]) {
    $XmlDocument.products.product | %{ $_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_) | Out-Null }
}
```

This code also works if `<products>` does not contain any child elements (i.e., it is a text element).

Answer (score 0):

```
<products id="col">
  <product code="id1" />
  <product code="id2" />
</products>
<products id="row">
  <product code="id3" />
  <product code="id4" />
</products>
```

I wonder if I want to delete the child node by parent node attribute id, how should I do?
Make the code to

```
<products id="col">
  <product code="id1" />
  <product code="id2" />
</products>
<products id="row">
</products>
```